# Selenium Script failed due to site slowness nature or network issue

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I'm running script from my Testng framework. Every time i run the script, some methods fail due to website responsiveness

I used all kinds of waits...ie explicit,Implicit,Webdriver wait, Fluent but still random test case failed

How to improve the situation?

Comment: Idk if I'm misunderstanding something, but it sounds like your problem has less to do with what type of wait you use and rather with the timeout being set which means that instead of focusing on the different types of waits, you should be increasing the amount of time before the wait functions timeout.

Comment: You have an ajax tag so I am guessing you have some ajax calls to wait for.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806124/selenium-cant-find-element-even-after-explicit-waiting-in-an-ajax-page

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 things you can do to improve the situation, and those being:

1. configure a longer timeout time for the waiting.
2. add another small predefined waiting time after the waittime with a max timeout, this gives the website some time to execute the javascript code. In some cases the page will be done loading but there is still javascript being executed in the background that is changing some elements on the page.

ofcource I cannot for shure tell you this will solve your problem because you weren't really specific or didn't give any way to replicate the problem, and I'm just guessing this might cause your problem. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out protractor, because it waits until the all elements & js loads in the page